# Javascript/React/Node: Writing values to an existing excel file with condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, reactjs

Is it possible in Javascript/React/Node to achieve this functionality?

Let's say I have an array of objects:

```
var obj = [ {'date' : 01/01/2019, 'value': 1}, {'date' : 02/01/2019, 'value': 2}, {'date' : 03/01/2019, 'value': 3}]
```

Then I want to write the values field of each object to an existing excel file with their corresponding date value.

From this excel file:

[image]

to this one below:

[image]

Is this achievable in JS? Thanks.

Comment: [https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-excel-export] **Node-excel-export** might help you

Comment: Thanks Rinkesh. But I need to put data on an existing excel file. Not create one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do what you want.

If you are using nodejs you can install this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx

Here is a example code of how you can read the values

```
'use strict'

const XLSX = require('xlsx');

const workbook = XLSX.readFile('./test.xlsx');

var stream = XLSX.stream.to_json(workbook, {raw:true});

const workSheet = workbook.Sheets.Sheet1;
console.log(workSheet["!ref"]); 
//With this function you can see the range of your sheet that had data
//You can create a function to parse this information
//and obtain the range of cell where you want to obtain the values
const valuesRange = ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1']; 
let desiredCell = [];
valuesRange.forEach(cell => desiredCell.push(workSheet[cell]));
const desiredValues = (desiredCell ? desiredCell.map(cell => cell.w) : undefined);
console.log(desiredValues); 
// This will return [ '1-Jan-19', '2-Jan-19', '3-Jan-19' ]

//Know you can do whatever you want with this values
// example a parse function to convert to 01/01/2019 and write to new file
```

If it is possible for you to use google spreadsheets I will recommend to do that.

Writing and reading functions are really easy. 
You will need to install https://www.npmjs.com/package/util and https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const util = require('util');

const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'];

module.exports = class SpreadSheetService {
  constructor(spreadsheetId) {
    this.spreadsheetId = spreadsheetId;
    this.jwt = new google.auth.JWT(<UserEmail>, null, <Base64Key>, SCOPES);
    this.sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth: this.jwt });
    this.readSpreadSheet = util.promisify(this.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get);
    this.updateSpreadSheet = util.promisify(this.sheets.spreadsheets.values.update);
  }

  async read(sheet, cell) {
    return this.readSpreadSheet({
      spreadsheetId: this.spreadsheetId,
      range: `${sheet}!${cell}`,
      valueRenderOption: 'UNFORMATTED_VALUE'
    });
  }

  async write(sheet, cell, value) {
    return this.updateSpreadSheet({
      spreadsheetId: this.spreadsheetId,
      valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED',
      range: `${sheet}!${cell}`,
      resource: { values: [[value]] }
    });
  }
};
```